# How can I force both tables to render in a single page with pagebreak set on "Id"?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I've been developing an SSRS report that contains two tables.

The first "table" uses DataSet "A" & second "table" uses DataSet B.

In both DataSet, an "Id" is common.

My requirement was to group data on "Id" in both the tables. That I did.

Two tables are within the same page and all PageBreak* properties are set to "True" on "Id" column.

The problem is SSRS renders the report with pagebreak for first "Table". After the first "Table", it starts rendering second table with page breaks.

How can I force both tables to render in a single page with pagebreak set on "Id" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split this into a master report and a subreport.  The master report would have a simplified Dataset which just returns a row for each "Id".  I would create a table using that Dataset and add a subreport object to the Detail row.  I would set Page Breaks "Between each instance of a group" on the Details Row Group.

The subreport version of the report would have the two existing tables.  I would add an "Id" parameter to the subreport Parameters and to both Datasets. I would remove the Page Break options from the subreport.

Finally, back in the main report, I would set the subreport object so that it passes the parameter for "Id", sourced from the Main report's dataset.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for sharing. Yes, this is the one or the other option is to combine/merge both these datasets. The problem with your suggested approch is, reports are integrated with sharepoint. The combining data sets approcach is ok, but need rework. No other solution seems work in this case. Anyways, Thanks.